# On the uniqueness of the solutions for $ y=x \frac{d y}{d x}-\left(\frac{d y}{d x}\right)^2 $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was solving a multiple select question:

The differential equation
$$
y=x \frac{d y}{d x}-\left(\frac{d y}{d x}\right)^2,
$$
has more than one solutions passing through the point

(a) $(0,1)$,

(b) $(1,1)$,

(c) $(2,1)$,

(d) $(2,-1)$.

My attempts:

i. I got $$y'=f(x,y)=\frac{x \pm \sqrt{x^2-4y}}{2}~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(*),$$while I couldn't proceed further,

ii. Any thing can be deduced from the fact: 'For the initial data $(2,1)$, $y'(2)$ is unique and for the data $(2,-1)$, $y'(2)$ is not unique' ?

iii. For the sake of Picard's theorem, we have $$|f(x,y_1)-f(x,y_2)|=\frac{2|y_1-y_2|}{\sqrt{x^2-4y_1}+\sqrt{x^2-4y_2}},$$
and thereby, there is a unique solution for the ODE $(*)$ with initial data $(2,-1)$ valid in some neighbourhood of $x=2$. But still we have two distinct $f(x,y)$'s, right?

How to deal such conditions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: $$y=xy'-(y')^2\\
-y=(y')^2-xy'\\
-\left(y-\frac{x^2}{4}\right)=(y')^2-xy'+\frac{x^2}{4}\\
-\left(y-\frac{x^2}{4}\right)=\left(y'-\frac{x}{2}\right)^2\\
u=-\left(y-\frac{x^2}{4}\right)\\
u=(u')^2\\
2x+C=\int\frac{\pm du}{2\sqrt u}\\
\left(2x+C\right)^2=u\\
y=\frac{x^2}{4}-\left(2x+C\right)^2\\
y=-\left(\frac{3x}{2}+C\right)\left(3x+C\right)\\
y=-\left(\frac{9}{2}x^2+\frac{9C}{2}x+C^2\right)\\
C=\frac{-9x/2\pm\sqrt{(9x/2)^2-4(9x^2/2+y)}}{2}$$
Using this, we can check $(c)$ and $(d)$ are the only correct answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe we can try to solve the equation. Let $p=\frac{dy}{dx}$. Differentiate once and we obtain $(x-2p)\frac{dp}{dx}=0$.

The first case is $x=2p$. We can get $y=\frac14x^2$. The second case is $p=C$. We can get $y=Cx-C^2$.

For (c)(d), the formulae give multiple solutions. For (a)(b), we put the initial data in and then see that there is no real solution for $\frac{dy}{dx}$ at this point.

Comment: This doesn’t quite answer the question. They’re looking for theoretical ways to determine when solutions exist uniquely. Moreover you are not given that the solution is second differentiable so, without further justification, you can’t claim to cover all solutions by taking $dp/dx$. And it needs justification to assume one of the two factors is *always* zero in $(x-2p)p’=0$.

Comment: @FShrike We need not find all the solutions. For (c)(d), we can work out two solutions by solving it. For (a)(b), we can prove that there is no solution. Also, general theory for uniqueness of solution is a hard problem.